# Java Generics: set List of superclass using List of subclass

Tags: java, generics, class, hierarchy

If I have a method in `MyClass` such as

```
setSuperClassList(List<Superclass>)
```

...should I be able to do this:

```
new MyClass().setSuperClassList(new ArrayList<Subclass>())
```

It appears this won't compile.  Why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `setSuperClassList(List<? extends Superclass>)`.

Also check [PECS](http://groups.google.com/group/juglugano/browse_thread/thread/c11531309ed37646) to see wether you should use `? extends` or `? super`.

Answer (score 6):

You are just doing the generics a bit wrong.  Add the `? extends` bit, and that will allow the passed in list to contain the SuperClass or any of its subclasses.

```
setSuperClassList(List<? extends Superclass>)
```

This is called setting an upper bound on the generics.

The statement `List<Superclass>` says that the List can only contain `SuperClass`.  This excludes any subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

It won't compile since`java.util.List` is not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Try `setSuperClassList(List<? extends Superclass>)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
setSuperClassList(List<? extends Superclass> list)
```

This will allow a list of any subclass of Superclass.